# JQuery Dialog Close Event

Tags: jquery-dialog

```
$("#termSheetPrinted").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            height: $(window).height() - 50,
            width: $(window).width() - 50,
            position: 'center',
            title: 'Term Sheet',
            beforeClose: function(event, ui) { $("#termSheetPrinted").html(''); },
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Print": function () {
                    $("#termSheetPrinted").jqprint();
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $("#termSheetPrinted").html('');
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

So, when I click 'Cancel', I can generate the dialog right over again and everything looks fine. If I click the 'X' in the upper right corner and generate it again, it doubles up, having not been cleared from the last time.

I tried adding the `beforeClose` event to clear the HTML, however it doesn't seem to be working.

How can I get it to clear and close properly from both 'Cancel', and hitting the 'X'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work if I bind it to `close` instead.

Shouldn't this work both ways though?